# Как заставить бота "ждать", пока пользователь не нажмёт инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, telebot

Я закинул в цикл создание сообщений с инлайн-кнопками. Проблема лишь в том, что бот выводит все сообщения с вопросами сразу. Мне нужно, чтобы перед отправлением очередного сообщения бот ждал нажатия инлайн-кнопки на текущем сообщении

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

questions = ["Твои увлечения",
             "Твой возраст",
             "Твой рост"]

answers = [["Спорт", "Рисование", "Игры", "Другое"],
           ["Меньше 18", "Меньше 30, но больше 18"],
           ["Около 170", "Больше 200"]]

bot.allow_sending_without_reply = False

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Вопросы появятся после ввода команды /quiz")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['quiz'])
def quiz_questions(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    for num, question in enumerate(questions):
        options = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        ans_options = answers[num]

        for option_i in range(len(ans_options)):
            option = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = ans_options[option_i], callback_data = f'{option_i}')
            options.add(option)

        question_message = f"{num+1}. {question}"
        
        bot.send_message(chat_id, question_message, reply_markup=options)


        # bot.register_next_step_handler(message, check_answer, num)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def check_answer(call):
    
    msg = f'{call.data}'
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

P.S. я ещё планирую переделать программу так, чтобы она меняла текст и кнопки текущего сообщения на текст и кнопки следующего. Если не сложно, подскажите как это можно грамотно реализовать)

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Это не решает мою проблему (ну либо я просто не понял, как это должно её решить)!
Суть в том, что я хочу использовать именно **инлайн-кнопки**, там такого не увидел (